# Image resampling, Memory Error

Tags: numpy, out-of-memory

**What I am trying:** I have a 23 by 23 numpy array which I have converted to image. After that I am trying to resample it 5000 times (The new image will have a size of 23*5000 by 23*5000) with nearest neighbor sampling. But I am getting Memory Error.

**My code is-**

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

img = Image.fromarray(aa)

img.show()

import scipy.ndimage

#print 'Original array:'
#print(aa)

#print 'Resampled by a factor of 2 with nearest interpolation:'
pppp=scipy.ndimage.zoom(aa, 5000, order=0)

img1 = Image.fromarray(pppp)


img1.show()
```

Where aa is my 23 by 23 array.

**What I want:** Is there any way to get rid of the memory error? Or is there any way to do it differently so that I can do what I am trying to do?

Comment: Why do you need such an extreme resample factor? Is nearest neighbor the only method you want to use?

Comment: No, I am not strict on that. Actually I am using a satellite image in which the data is given as 5000 m resolution. But I want a resolution of 1 m actually.

Answer (score 0):

Resampling will change the array-size needed to store the newly sampled image.

Assuming you are using a grayscale-image (np.uint8), an image of size (23*5000, 23*5000) will approximately need > 12GB of memory!

There is not much you can do (besides buying more memory), as most image-resizers are assuming, this is an in-memory operation!

(Maybe some resizers could be tuned to work with numpy's memmap, but this will need modifications and will also be probably quite slow)